# I'm getting the following error and can't work it out

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and started putting together the below code. I'm trying to get the `fread` function working correctly but I'm getting an error.

I've tried a few ways to fix it but of course if I don't know what's causing it I'm never going to fix it.

I'm hoping someone could help me out.

**Error**

```
unknown@ubuntu:~$ ./attack.py -f wordfile.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./attack.py", line 63, in <module>
    print fread(list)
  File "./attack.py", line 20, in fread
    flist = open(list).readlines()
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found`
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import sys, getopt, socket, fileinput, traceback
import dns.query, dns.message, dns.name, adns
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


def usage():
    print "-h --help: help\n"
    print "-f --file: File to read bruteforce domain list from.\n"
    print "-p --proxy: Proxy address and port. e.g http://192.168.1.64:8080\n"
    print "-d --domain: Domain to bruteforce.\n"
    print "-t --thread: Thread count.\n"
    print "-e: Turn debug on.\n"
    sys.exit()

def fread(list, *args):
   flist = open(list).readlines()
   return flist

def addcheck(fcontent):
   data =[]
   c=adns.init()
   for sub in file:
     SubDomain = fcontent + domain
     data[SubDomain] = c.synchronous(SubDomain, adns.rr.A)
   return data


def main(argv):
  list = None
  proxy = None
  domain = None
  FILE= None
  try:
     opts, argv =getopt.getopt(argv, "h:f:p:d:t:e",["help", "file=", "proxy=", "domain=", "thread="])

  except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print str(err)
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

  for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
          usage()
          sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-f", "--file"):
          list = arg
      elif opt in ("-p", "--proxy"):
          proxy = arg
      elif opt in ("-d", "--domain"):
          domain = arg
      elif opt in ("-t", "--thread"):
          thread = arg
      elif opt in '-e':
          global _debug

print fread(list)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Please be carefull with your indent, use pep8 `sudo apt-get install pep8` to test your code before posting :)

Comment: @VivienG: better still, use `flake8` and catch many more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the `list` type object here:

```
print fread(list)
```

This is *outside* of the `main` function, so `list` is still bound to the built-in type.

You probably meant that line to be part of the `main()` function. If so, indent it further to match the rest of the code in the function.

You really should not use `list` as a variable name, however. There already is a built-in [type of that name](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list); as a result your indentation error gave you a confusing exception message. Perhaps `fname` or `filename` would have been a better choice.

Comment: The person who asked the question will not know what that means.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, rofl that simple! i sat here for ages googling it :( thanks. Now just need to replace those \n's in the output.

Comment: just waiting for the timeout of 7min before it will allow me to accept it.